# Send data from textbox to website textbox using c#?

Tags: c#, html, browser

I have been trying to enter data from my c# form and when I click to submit button on my form it should be transferred to `TextBox` of website...here

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("email")[1].SetAttribute("Value", textBox2.Text);
   webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("pass")[1].SetAttribute("Value", textBox3.Text);
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form")[1].InvokeMember("submit");
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   webBrowser1.Navigate("gmail.com");//Your link
   webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted); 
}
```

what I have done is that open a link in web browser and to search Attributes to enter data in it but its giving an error that `"Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1."` when I change index to zero it gives the same error.

Comment: My guess is that `GetElementsByName` either doesn't return an array or you need to use `[0]` to get the first element.

Answer (score 0):

`GetElementsByName("email")[1]` Means there are at least two elements with the name "email" and you want to select the second one as [1] specifies the index of the array and arrays start from index 0.

In your case it seems that there is only one element with the name "email" (possibly the rest of the elements you are trying to get as well, assuming an element with that name exists) which means you will need to get the first item in the array, in other words `GetElementsByName("email")[0]`

Comment: Sorry but i am not getting what u said can you please do a little bit correction in my code where i am wrong?

Comment: I already did in the answer above. What don't you understand exactly ? The GetElementsByName methods return a "list" of items, not just one, the [1] at the end is to selected which index of the array to use. In your case you are trying to access the second item [1] in the "list" that probably contains only one item, in that case you should be using [0] to get the first item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

The Code has been amended for your Array.

```
GetElementsByName("email")[0].
```

Comment: Have you amended your Array?
So Email is [0], Pass is [1]; Form is [2]?